# What should look like example network configuration for maas/juju?

Tags: juju, maas

I have still problem with configuring maas/juju. And I want to know what is best configuration(simplest) for maas/juju? If someone have graphic of it I will be happy.

Comment: what's wrong with the [juju docs](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html)? it's pretty straight forward, and graphic examples are included as sample code snippets.

Comment: There isn't any information about network configuration.

Comment: search *network configuration* in the page. it's under the LXC entry.

Comment: I agree with Eliran CTRL-F and search for network on the docs page.

Comment: Still there is not any example graphic.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the documentation for [MAAS online too](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/) if that helps. MAAS assumes you have several nodes, and the easiest configuration would be for these to be in a separate subnet with DHCP controlled by MAAS.

I'm not entirely sure what you expect a diagram to show you. If you could explain a little more what you are trying to do or what you expect a diagram to show, we may be able to help you further.

Comment: I have problem with network, i think with dns because when I check juju status I get "nameNode.localdomain" but I want IP address. I want this because when I scale my service with juju another nodes can't connect to "nameNode.localdomain" and they don't search IP addresses so I have problems.

Comment: I am having similar difficulty, I think. I opened a similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377640/proper-maas-configuration

Comment: I think the issue is with the maas documentation. There is no clear indication of what the network structure should be. I agree that it would make sense for there to be 2 interfaces on the maas server, one that is public (connects to the rest of the network), and one that is private (connects to the nodes, hands out IPs, etc). But the documentation seems to use a single interface, meaning that either the nodes are on the same subnet as the rest of my network, or nothing is connected to the rest of the network/internet