# Proper MaaS configuration

Tags: server, maas

Working with Ubuntu Server 12.04 maas installation, and I am having trouble making sense of the official documentation:

[Docs](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/index.html)

I might be missing something, but I can't find any documentation on what the networking configuration should be. I would assume that there needs to be two network interfaces on the controller, one connected to the rest of the network/internet (public), and one for the nodes (private).

When installing, you select a primary interface, which becomes eth0 after installation in:

/etc/network/interfaces

I selected my public interface as the primary during install. Now I guess I need to set up the private interface, eth1, by hand? In the docs:

[Cluster Configuration](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/cluster-configuration.html)

There is some additional interface, lxcbr0. Are there missing steps in the documentation?

Please let me know if I need to clarify this. Would love to contribute to the docs if I can get this working.

This is my layout:

[image]

EDIT: I am able to register nodes with this setup, but I am still unable to commission nodes. This may have to do with the fact that the nodes behind the maas-dhcp server do not have access to the internet

Comment: Finishing drawing now: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1JSn6DF82t7v3FNZr3h9MUhpshPaRrNc1llSm2S7j-_A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation that would confirm that this is the correct kind of layout.

Comment: Similar question, I think. Never answered: http://askubuntu.com/questions/205086/what-should-look-like-example-network-configuration-for-maas-juju

Comment: In the following tutorial, the dude goes over setup, outlining the config he used in virtualbox: http://ideasnet.wordpress.com/2013/10/17/ubuntu-server-how-to-install-metal-as-a-server-maas-cloud-infrastructure-in-ubuntu-12-04-3-lts-server-edition-part-1/

Comment: Trying with LTS. Question updated

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding` and `ip route show`? Also, did you set any static routes on your router by chance? What range of IP addresses are you using behind the MaaS server? What range of addresses does your network use in front of the MaaS server and behind the router?